# Map between a connected covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, covering-spaces

Let $p : Y \to X$ be a covering map and $Y$ is connected. There exist another covering map $q : Y \to X$ and a map $r : Y \to Y$ such that $p \circ r = q$ Is it true that $r$ is a covering map of $Y$? I am not able to get any counter example for this.

Comment: The answer is positive if $X$ is locally connected. I think it's wrong in general, but I forgot the details. This surely has been discussed on the site before.

Comment: Any book, can you suggest for locally connected case?

Comment: Don't remember references. I suggest solving this as an exercise. As a starting point: locally connected is relevant cause it means that the decomposition of the preimage of an evenly covered subset into components that get mapped homeomorphically onto that evenly covered subset is unique.